# running NativeScript setup script for cli

Tags: bash, nativescript

I am having a difficult time getting native script up and running with the cli.

I followed the setup script which does everything for you.  I did this on node 4.4.6.  Which is listed as stable for right now.

Earlier I had attempted this on 6.2.1 as well.

I have xCode running and I followed allowed the start up script to do all of the installs on 4.4.6.  With 6.2.1 I did the set up manually.

In both cases I am getting the a successful build message.

```
** BUILD SUCCEEDED **

Project successfully built.
Using  /Users/steven/projects/nativescript/conf2/confRps/platforms/ios/build/emulator/confRps.app
Starting iOS Simulator
```

Immediately followed by SecTaskLoad

```
Jun 24 15:11:53 jays-MacBook-Pro backboardd[34043]: SecTaskCopyDebugDescription: confRps[40147]
Jun 24 15:11:53 jays-MacBook-Pro backboardd[34043]: SecTaskLoadEntitlements failed error=22 cs_flags=200, task->pid_self=-1
Jun 24 15:11:53 jays-MacBook-Pro backboardd[34043]: SecTaskCopyDebugDescription: confRps[40147]
Jun 24 15:11:53 jays-MacBook-Pro backboardd[34043]: SecTaskLoadEntitlements failed error=2
```

I am getting an the iphone emulator to appear but nothing is working with the current buttons I have installed.

I know others have installed native script wondering what things I need to look for in debug this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [answer](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/2291#issuecomment-225782501) might help you to solve your problem, however it would help if you give some more info about the problem and NativeScript version. In regard to that in case you want to use old project it would be good idea to remove the platform with `tns platform remove ios` and to add it again `tns platform add ios`.